# FLTK C++ Fl_line don't draw

Tags: c++, fltk

I was tasked to debug a code that was meant to draw a simple polygon out of 4 points using FLTK. The `MyWindow` class derive from `Fl_Window`. The `Shape` class is the parent class for `ClosedPolyline`. Both `MyWindow` and `Shape` hold a vector to draw all of the shapes.

The problem is that after compiling and run, `win.show()` opens an empty window without any drawing. I'm puzzled to understand this behavior.

Here is the code (I've omitted some of the parts that are not related to drawing `ClosedPolyline`):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Draw.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Widget.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Device.H>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <math.h>

struct Point {
int x,y;
Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) { }
};

class Shape{
public:

Point point(int idx) const {
return (points[idx]);
}
unsigned int points_size() const {
return points.size();}

void draw() /*const*/{
draw_lines();
}

void add(Point p){ points.push_back(p); }

protected:
virtual void draw_lines() {}

private:
std::vector<Point> points;
};

class ClosedPolyline: public Shape {
public:
/*ClosedPolyline(std::initializer_list<Point> pp) {
if (pp.size() > 0) {
for (Point p: pp)
add(p);
}
}
*/
ClosedPolyline(Point a1, Point a2, Point a3, Point a4){
    add(a1); add(a2); add(a3); add(a4);
}
protected:
void draw_lines() override{
for (unsigned int i=1; i<points_size(); ++i){
fl_line(point(i-1).x, point(i-1).y, point(i).x, point(i).y);
}
}
};

class MyWindow: public Fl_Window {
public:
MyWindow(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char* title = 0)
: Fl_Window(x, y, w, h, title) {}
void Attach(Shape s) {
shapes.push_back(&s);
}
//void draw_shapes(){draw();}
protected:
void draw() override{
for(Shape * s: shapes) {
s->draw();
//s.draw();
}
}

private:
std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
};
```

And here is the `main()` function:

```
int main() {
MyWindow win(100, 100, 600, 400, "C++ Test task");

ClosedPolyline p{Point{100, 100}, Point{100, 200}, Point{500, 100}, Point{500, 200}};
win.Attach(p);
win.end();
win.show();
return (Fl::run());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a look at your `MyWindow::Attach` function:

```
void Attach(Shape s) {
shapes.push_back(&s);
}
```

In the function, the argument `s` is passed by value. That means it's the same as a *local variable* inside the function. And as such it will go out of scope and be destructed once the function return.

Saving a pointer to that variable will lead to you saving a stray pointer, pointing to a non-existing object. Dereferencing that pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), turning your whole program *ill-formed* and invalid.

One way to solve the problem is to make sure that the object don't go out of scope. This can be done by using *smart pointers* like e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). And to use it from the beginning already when you define the variable `p` in the `main` function.

---

Another way to solve your problem is to assume that the `Shape` passed to `Attach` will have a lifetime that outlives the `Shape` object, and you could therefore pass the `Shape` *by reference*:

```
void Attach(Shape& s) {
    shapes.push_back(&s);
}
```

Now you no longer get a copy of the `Shape` object, and push a pointer to the original object (in your case the object `p` in the `main` function). Dereferencing the pointer will be valid as long as the original object is alive and in scope.

Comment: I get your point. However, I'm prohibited from modifying the `main()` function, so I figured that to achieve the same result, I can instead fill the vector with copies of the shapes and call `draw()` using those copies. The result, however, is still the same, a blank window. Here is the edited `MyWindow()` :

Comment: @NgocDuyNguyen The problem is that the copying is creating a `Shape` object, note a `ClosedPolyline` object. While the `Shape` object will have the vector of `Point` from the original, it haven an empty `draw_lines` function that does nothing. Exactly the behavior you have.

Comment: @NgocDuyNguyen Updated my answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for that. I feel like a dumbass for not thinking of it deeper before asking. However, right after the first line from the first 2 points in the vector is drawn, I get the exception `SIGSEGV`. I've made sure the offset for the vector is not out of bound. Searching for this exception doesn't give me much answer as to why it happens in this case.

Comment: Can you explain to me why no matter what order I call `fl_line()`, it always crash with a segmentation fault (`SIGSEGV`) after drawing the first line. I've used a for loop to print all the values in the vector to illustrate that they are within bound, and thus I can't think of any other factors that may trigger this exception. Here's my edited code: https://pastebin.com/ueMMvLf5.  Can it be a compiler error? (I'm building in MinGW with FLTK 1.3.4)

Comment: @NgocDuyNguyen That is an unrelated problem, and should warrant a new question. Before you post it though, I recommend that you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to at least *locate* where the crash happens in your program.

Comment: I've finished reading the blog, definitely very useful. The last segment was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460759/fltk-sigsegv-segmentation-fault-when-calling-fl-line/46462827#46462827

Answer (score 0):

I try run that code in VS2015 and get a lot of error( of course fix attach window pass by reference ) But when I run to linux , it can draw, So I think you should move to linux.

Comment: Wow thanks for that. I never know the difference would be so radical. Did you run the fix in my comment with @Someprogrammerdude or the code above in the question? I haven't got linux (yet) so I'd be appreciate if you can test it for me there.

Comment: I've manage to solve the second problem with a solution in here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460759/fltk-sigsegv-segmentation-fault-when-calling-fl-line/46462827#46462827